# Comparing two xml files using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XML files :

File "a":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <catalog>
  <cd>d</cd>
  <cd>e</cd>
  <cd>f</cd>
  <cd>c</cd>
</catalog>
```

File "b":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>a</cd>
  <cd>b</cd>
  <cd>c</cd>
</catalog>
```

I want to compare File `b` against File `a` and get those records which are only present in file `b`.

i.e. Expected output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <catalog>
  <cd>a</cd>
  <cd>b</cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: I am fairly new to this.

Comment: I tried by nesting a "for-each" loop but the problem arises because of the fact that we cannot change the value of variables once assigned

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: There is no preference towards xsl 1.0 or 2.0 .  Any will do

Comment: file "a" does not have  <cd>a</cd> element .. so it will be there in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, then this can be done very simply (and efficiently) by using a **key**. Assuming you are processing the "b" file:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="cd" match="cd" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="cd[not(key('cd', ., document('a.xml')))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How to run the command ? Currently I am using xsl transform command from CMD like msxsl -o Output.xml Input.xml Logic.xsl

Comment: @MandarKale This has nothing to do with the question above. Post your own question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution can be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="compareWith" select="'a.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:if test="not(document($compareWith)//cd = .)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main point is that we check whether the actual `cd` content is not present in the document that is to be compared (`$compareWith`)